# Google Transition API Not Found

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services

[image]

I have installed the Google Play Service Location package but i'm able to find ActivityTransition class in my project.

I followed this link.
https://android.jlelse.eu/googles-new-transition-api-for-android-d5d9d6904883

Answer (score 0):

The reason these API's are unavailable is simply caused by the fact that the current version (Stable) of `GooglePlayServices` that `Xamarin.Android` provides is 11.4.2, the same can be read even in the image that you have uploaded.

Since these API's were added in GooglePlayServices 12.0.0, Now if you have to use the Transition API then you will have to download the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location` Nuget to prerelease(70.1501.0) and since it is a pre-release Nuget there is no telling if there are any bugs in it or not.

For reference check these:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140484/xamarin-android-google-activity-recognition-transition-api-not-working

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140480/xamarin-android-google-activity-recognition-transition-api-not-working